# How to convert a tibble in as many tables as categorical levels variables

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, flextable, gtsummary

I have the following tibble

```
structure(list(blockLabel = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("auditory_only", 
"bimodal_focus_auditory", "bimodal_focus_visual", "divided", 
"visual_only"), class = "factor"), trial_resp.corr = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("pilot01", 
"pilot02", "pilot03"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 
74L, 0L, 12L, 71L, 69L, 70L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 77L, 11L, 12L, 
71L, 70L, 67L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 75L, 0L, 11L, 71L, 69L, 69L, 12L
), tc = c(12, 72, 72, 144, 12, 12, 72, 72, 144, 12, 12, 72, 72, 
144, 12, 12, 72, 72, 144, 12, 12, 72, 72, 144, 12, 12, 72, 72, 
144, 12), freq = c(0, 1.38888888888889, 4.16666666666667, 51.3888888888889, 
0, 100, 98.6111111111111, 95.8333333333333, 48.6111111111111, 
100, 0, 1.38888888888889, 2.77777777777778, 53.4722222222222, 
91.6666666666667, 100, 98.6111111111111, 97.2222222222222, 46.5277777777778, 
8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 1.38888888888889, 4.16666666666667, 
52.0833333333333, 0, 91.6666666666667, 98.6111111111111, 95.8333333333333, 
47.9166666666667, 100)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

I would like to create three different tables according to the levels of **participant** variable. More or less the final result should be like the following one:

[image]

I have started scripting the following code (since I am looking for to do this via a dplyr, apply family, loops or map function)

```
  list %>%  as_data_frame() %>%
  select(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant, Freq, freq) %>% 
  map(~ flextable(.x))
```

But unfortunately, I get the following error code:

```
Error in flextable(.x) : is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE
```

I am not an expert in this method thus if you would have something to suggest about fixing the problem and sharing knowledge to achieve the final result, please just let me know (in passing I specify that Correctness corresponds to 1 and Incorrcetness to 0 of trial_resp.corr variable)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method where we modify the 'trial_resp.corr' values to 'Incorrectness', 'Correctness' based on 0, 1 values, then `select` the columns of interest, `split` by the 'participant' column to create a `list` of datasets,  loop over the `list` with `map`, reshape data from long to wide with `pivot_wider` and then convert to `flextable`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(flextable)
library(stringr)
library(janitor)
lst1 <-  df1 %>% 
  mutate( trial_resp.corr = recode(trial_resp.corr, 
             '0'= 'Incorrectness', '1' = "Correctness")) %>%
  select(blockLabel, trial_resp.corr, participant, Freq,
  `Freq%` = freq) %>%
  split(.$participant) %>% 
  map(~ .x  %>% 
        select(-participant)  %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = trial_resp.corr, 
                    values_from = c(Freq, `Freq%`), values_fill = 0, 
            names_glue ="{trial_resp.corr}{str_remove(.value, 'Freq' )}") %>%
        adorn_totals() %>%
        mutate(across(ends_with("%"),
               ~ replace(.x, n(), 
         100 *get(str_remove(cur_column(), 
                               fixed("%")))[n()]/sum(Incorrectness[n()], 
     Correctness[n()])))) %>%
        mutate(across(ends_with("%"),~  round(.x, digits = 2)))%>%
        
        flextable)
```

If we want to create objects in the global env

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
lst1[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. If you would not mind I would like to add the final row with the total where there are numbers in the table. Do not feel forced, since it is really a great result

Comment: @creativity do you need to add the total for the `%` columns.  For the correctness%, it would be greater than 100 if we get the sum

Comment: possibly yes but that will be quite difficult. Because the final percentage of each value under columns 2 and 3 out of the whole sum of them (for instance in this case, correct response percentage should be 234/(234+78))

Comment: many thanks. That was so clever

Comment: Just a little curiosity. In case I would like to round the number of digits under % columns? I have used the following code `flextable() %>% colformat_num(j = c("Incorrectness%", "Correctness%"), digits = 2)`. It does not seem to work, above all for the total percentage.  Or also the `mutate(across(3:4, round, 2))` after `select(-participant)` but seem to work for everything but those final rows of percentage total.

Comment: @creativity you can do the `mutate(across(ends_with("%"), round, digits = 2))` just before the `flextable` call

Comment: I have tried but it does not work

Comment: pretty stunning!!

Comment: @creativity thanks, I did comment below your update, but someone has deleted it.  Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following (for + dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
dfs <- list()

for (prt in levels(df$participant)){
  dfs[[prt]] <- df %>% filter(participant == prt) %>% select(-participant)
}
```

You get the three tables for any required further manipulations:

```
> dfs
$pilot01
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   blockLabel             trial_resp.corr  Freq    tc   freq
   <fct>                  <fct>           <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 auditory_only          0                   0    12   0   
 2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0                   1    72   1.39
 3 bimodal_focus_visual   0                   3    72   4.17
 4 divided                0                  74   144  51.4 
 5 visual_only            0                   0    12   0   
 6 auditory_only          1                  12    12 100   
 7 bimodal_focus_auditory 1                  71    72  98.6 
 8 bimodal_focus_visual   1                  69    72  95.8 
 9 divided                1                  70   144  48.6 
10 visual_only            1                  12    12 100   

$pilot02
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   blockLabel             trial_resp.corr  Freq    tc   freq
   <fct>                  <fct>           <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 auditory_only          0                   0    12   0   
 2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0                   1    72   1.39
 3 bimodal_focus_visual   0                   2    72   2.78
 4 divided                0                  77   144  53.5 
 5 visual_only            0                  11    12  91.7 
 6 auditory_only          1                  12    12 100   
 7 bimodal_focus_auditory 1                  71    72  98.6 
 8 bimodal_focus_visual   1                  70    72  97.2 
 9 divided                1                  67   144  46.5 
10 visual_only            1                   1    12   8.33

$pilot03
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   blockLabel             trial_resp.corr  Freq    tc   freq
   <fct>                  <fct>           <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 auditory_only          0                   1    12   8.33
 2 bimodal_focus_auditory 0                   1    72   1.39
 3 bimodal_focus_visual   0                   3    72   4.17
 4 divided                0                  75   144  52.1 
 5 visual_only            0                   0    12   0   
 6 auditory_only          1                  11    12  91.7 
 7 bimodal_focus_auditory 1                  71    72  98.6 
 8 bimodal_focus_visual   1                  69    72  95.8 
 9 divided                1                  69   144  47.9 
10 visual_only            1                  12    12 100
```